# Can't get nginx resolver to work

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, amazon-ecs

I'm facing issue with nginx when a container in network change his IP , i can access it in Linux OS But nginx didnt resolve the new IP... I searched alot about a solution and i see that nginx tell us to use resolver directive then i tried it But nothing changed.... can't get this resolver to work, there is something that should i check ? I tried everything....

Could Simeone help me With some Hint?

Obs: im using ecs fargate.

Thanks in advanced.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.7"

x-aws-loadbalancer: ***

services:

  i***-root:
    image: ***
    container_name: i***-root
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - i***-angular
      - i***-react

  i***-angular:
    image: ***
    container_name: i***-angular

  i***-react:
    image: ***
    container_name: i***-react

x-aws-cloudformation:
    Resources:
        I***angularService:
            Properties:
                EnableExecuteCommand: true
        I***reactService:
            Properties:
                EnableExecuteCommand: true
        I***rootService:
            Properties:
                EnableExecuteCommand: true
        I***angularTaskDefinition:
            Properties:
                Cpu: 2048
                Memory: 4096
                TaskRoleArn: ***
        I***reactTaskDefinition:
            Properties:
                Cpu: 2048
                Memory: 4096
                TaskRoleArn: ***
        I***rootTaskDefinition:
            Properties:
                Cpu: 2048
                Memory: 4096
                TaskRoleArn: ***
        I***rootTCP80TargetGroup:
            Properties:
                HealthCheckPath: /
        I***rootTCP443TargetGroup:
            Properties:
                Protocol: HTTPS
                HealthCheckPath: /
        I***rootTCP443Listener:
            Properties:
                Protocol: HTTPS
                Certificates: 
                    - CertificateArn: ***
```

**Dockerfile of "i***-root":**

```
FROM node:16 as build-root

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY map.json ./
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

COPY ./public /app/dist/

FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx/nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-custom.conf
COPY nginx/nginx-custom443.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-custom443.conf
COPY nginx/***-cert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/***-cert.pem
COPY nginx/***-private.pem /etc/ssl/certs/***-private.pem

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=build-root /app/dist .

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**nginx-custom.conf (where i tried to apply the resolver solution)**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    resolver 172.16.0.23 ipv6=off valid=10s;
    set $upstream_endpoint http://***-react;

    location /***-react/ {
        rewrite ^/***-react/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header IdRef $http_IdRef;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;          
        fastcgi_read_timeout 999999;
        proxy_connect_timeout 999999;
        proxy_send_timeout   999999;
        proxy_read_timeout   999999;
        send_timeout 999999;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }
}
```

But how i said before anything changed with this resolver directive .... looks like that nginx keep caching the dns, i tried to use google dns 8.8.8.8 or /etc/resolve.conf nameserver but anything works.... i'm a little confused with it.

I followed nginx documentation and there said that resolver directive should fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide your docker-compose?

Comment: @Turdie I updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: So why are you using the resolver and whats that ip 172.16.0.23. Can you do for example `dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats google.com. @172.16.0.23` to check if that ip even can resolve dns records or nslookup

Comment: @Turdie this IP is aws dns, how i Said i tried Google dns too

Comment: Resolver is only when you need to resolve internal dns records. So the AWS dns won't work because that's dns is not aware of your internal network same goes for Google dns

Comment: @Turdie got it, what should i do? I tried to use the nameserver from /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but i would leave it out

Comment: The issue is when the container in proxy_pass change the IP, nginx keep trying the old one... this resolver should fix the issue , do u think that issue is With this dns Server? I mean: "resolver 172.16.0.23" (this ip)

Comment: Idk that should i try ...

Comment: You might need to map the vhost to a file on your system using a volume, and then change the proxy pass that way, and of course nginx needs to be reloaded after that

Answer (score 0):

I would use this one

https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/tree/main/docs

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.example
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
```